# Why does a segmentation fault occur and how can we avoid doing so?

Tags: c

Is there any way to free elements up to the end of the array?

For example, while freeing from the 6th to the end as:

---

```
char *str = "Hello, World\n";
char *ptr = str+6;
free(ptr);
```

---

gives a "Segmentation fault"!

Are there ways to acheive so??

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Truncate the string?

Comment: Why is this tagged r?

Comment: You are trying to free a string literal (from middle), which is UB in C. You call free() only if allocated some memory using `*alloc()` functions. If you want to only the 1st 6 chars, then use an array and copy the 1st 6 chars into it (and terminate it with `0` if you want a *string*).

Answer (score 5):

> Why does a segmentation fault occur

Because you're trying to free memory that has not been allocated with `malloc`. And if it had been allocated with `malloc`, it wouldn't work because you're not pointing to the beginning of the memory.

> Are there ways to acheive so?

Are there ways to take memory that has not been allocated with `malloc` and add it to the pool of free memory available to `malloc`? No, that would make no sense. Especially as the memory in question is read-only.